# "so many ...that"

Tags: grammaticality, syntactic-analysis, subordinate-clauses

> "There were so many webs, that the town looked like something from a horror movie. "

I understand the meaning of this sentence but not the grammar. 
What is the grammatical function of the clause *"that the town looked like..."*?

Can anyone help me parse this sentence? This is what I have so far: subj- There
verb- were, predicate - many, adv - so

Comment: The _so `X` that `S`_ construction consists of two parts: a measure of some property `X` marked with _so_ (_so high, so many webs, so little money, so interesting_) followed by a result clause `S` marked with _that_ (respectively, _that nobody can climb it, that it looked like a horror movie, that they can't afford food, that I decided to stay another day_). The result clause illustrates the degree asserted for `X`. A stressed _so_ is often used to mean _very_ (_I was **so** mad_), but that's baby talk; _so_ requires a _that_ clause to make sense.

Comment: So, "that the town looked.like..." is an adverb modifying so?

Comment: Is there a name for these kinds of constructions that have two parts?

Comment: No, the _that_ clause is not an adverb, and it doesn't modify _so_. _So_ is part of the construction, like _that_; neither word has any meaning independent of the construction. There are thousands of such multi-part constructions in English, like comparative (_more important than that book_), superlative (_the most important of all_), equative (_as important as you think_), and [the _let alone_ construction](http://lingo.stanford.edu/sag/papers/fillmore+88.pdf). Most have no special name; they're the norm, not anything special.

Comment: The comma might be confounding the sense. I wouldn't expect one there as it separates the *So X that Y* construction.

Comment: I have added the tag subordinate clauses as grammar  is too vague. As we have a lot of subclauses is would make things clearer if it were possibe to add something in brackets, eg subordinate clauses (consequence/result).

Answer (score 1):

The example sentence has a very close semantic realtionship to the following:

*There were many webs, **so that** the town looked like something from a horror movie.*

In this sentence, ***so*** is the head of a prepositional phrase functioning as an adjunct of result.

In the original sentence *so* is an adverb of degree modifying ***many***. It licenses the post head content clause following *webs* which expresses the result of there being so many webs. The net effect is thus essentially the same.

We can see that there is a difference between *so* as head of a prepositional phrase and adverb as we can drop the subordinate clause *that the town looked like...* in the original, but not in the version above.

*There were so many webs.*

*
*There were many webs, so.*

ref: CaGEL p734

Comment: This would be _so_ as a 'preposition' in CaGEL terminology, then? A preposition that requires a _that_-clause object, in this case. I'd  prefer to view _so `Adj`/such `NP`  that `S`_ as a construction with its own affordances.

Answer (score 0):

Clauses that describe consequences are called clauses of result in English terminology. The traditional name in Latin grammar is consecutive clauses.
Clauses of result belong to the group of adverbial clauses.
The basic structures are

1 so that-clause (describing consequence/result)

2 so + adjective that-clause (consequence/result).

Examples

1a The gravestones were covered with moss so that it was impossible to read the names on them. (Longman DCE)

2a It was so cold that the water froze.

Of course, there are variants.

You can make such sentences clearer by inserting "consequence":

1b The gravestone were covered with moss.
The consequence was that it was impossible to read the names on them.

2b It was so cold and the consequence was that the water froze.

Answer (score 0):

In comments, John Lawler wrote:

> The *so `X` that `S`* construction consists of two parts: a measure of some property `X` marked with *so* (*so high, so many webs, so little money, so interesting*) followed by a result clause `S` marked with *that* (respectively, *that nobody can climb it, that it looked like a horror movie, that they can't afford food, that I decided to stay another day*). The result clause illustrates the degree asserted for `X`. A stressed *so* is often used to mean *very* (*I was **so** mad*), but that's baby talk; *so* requires a *that* clause to make sense.

Then following a comment by the OP asking whether *that the town looked like* is an adverb modifying *so*, also:

> No, the *that* clause is not an adverb, and it doesn't modify *so*. *So* is part of the construction, like *that*; neither word has any meaning independent of the construction. There are thousands of such multi-part constructions in English, like comparative (*more important than that book*), superlative (*the most important of all*), equative (*as important as you think*), and [the *let alone* construction](http://lingo.stanford.edu/sag/papers/fillmore+88.pdf). Most have no special name; they're the norm, not anything special.

Comment: Perhaps the downvoter would propound the theory they think so superior. An unexplained downvote of an answer so obviously at the scholarly end of the continuum is against the spirit of the site. Note that the answerer did not need to add supporting references here as this was submitted as a 'comment', and rightly converted to a community wiki by a moderator.

Answer (score -3):

*That the town* is just a follow-on bit of detail. It means that the number of spider webs **made it look like** something from a horror movie.